# Paste clipboard content to a window

Tags: c++, qt, clipboard, xlib

I am writing an over-simplified clipboard manager for personal use and I am trying to implement a feature where I will click in a text from clipboard history and it will paste to the window I am working.

[CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) has this feature so I am trying to see how it is done there.
I took the code from there that I believe it does what I want:

sleeptimer.h

```
/*
    Copyright (c) 2020, Lukas Holecek <hluk@email.cz>

    This file is part of CopyQ.

    CopyQ is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    CopyQ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with CopyQ.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

#ifndef SLEEPTIMER_H
#define SLEEPTIMER_H

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QElapsedTimer>

#include <cmath>

class SleepTimer final
{
public:
    explicit SleepTimer(int timeoutMs)
        : m_timeoutMs(timeoutMs)
    {
        m_timer.start();
    }

    bool sleep()
    {
        QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents, 5);
        return m_timer.elapsed() < m_timeoutMs;
    }

    int remaining() const
    {
        const auto remaining = static_cast<int>(m_timeoutMs - m_timer.elapsed());
        return std::max(0, remaining);
    }

private:
    QElapsedTimer m_timer;
    int m_timeoutMs;
};

inline void waitFor(int ms)
{
    SleepTimer t(ms);
    while (t.sleep()) {}
}

#endif // SLEEPTIMER_H
```

x11platformwindow.h

```
/*
    Copyright (c) 2020, Lukas Holecek <hluk@email.cz>

    This file is part of CopyQ.

    CopyQ is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    CopyQ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with CopyQ.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

#ifndef X11PLATFORMWINDOW_H
#define X11PLATFORMWINDOW_H


#include <X11/Xlib.h>

#include <memory>

class AppConfig;
class QWidget;

class X11PlatformWindow
{
public:

    explicit X11PlatformWindow(Window winId);

    void raise() ;

    void pasteClipboard() ;

    void copy();

    bool isValid() const;

private:
    bool waitForFocus(int ms);

    void sendKeyPress(int modifier, int key);

    Window m_window;
};

Window getCurrentWindow();

#endif // X11PLATFORMWINDOW_H
```

x11platformwindow.cpp

```
/*
    Copyright (c) 2020, Lukas Holecek <hluk@email.cz>

    This file is part of CopyQ.

    CopyQ is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    CopyQ is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with CopyQ.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
*/

#include "sleeptimer.h"
#include "x11platformwindow.h"

#include <unistd.h>
#include <QX11Info>
#include <QTimer>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>

#ifdef HAS_X11TEST
#   include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#endif

void waitMs(int msec)
{
    if (msec <= 0)
        return;

    QEventLoop loop;
    QTimer t;
    QObject::connect(&t, &QTimer::timeout, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    t.start(msec);
    loop.exec();
}

void simulateKeyPress(Display *display, Window window, unsigned int modifiers, unsigned int key)
{
    XKeyEvent event;
    XEvent *xev = reinterpret_cast<XEvent *>(&event);
    event.display     = display;
    event.window      = window;
    event.root        = DefaultRootWindow(display);
    event.subwindow   = None;
    event.time        = CurrentTime;
    event.x           = 1;
    event.y           = 1;
    event.x_root      = 1;
    event.y_root      = 1;
    event.same_screen = True;
    event.keycode     = XKeysymToKeycode(display, key);
    event.state       = modifiers;

    event.type = KeyPress;
    XSendEvent(display, window, True, KeyPressMask, xev);
    XSync(display, False);

    event.type = KeyRelease;
    XSendEvent(display, window, True, KeyPressMask, xev);
    XSync(display, False);
}

class X11WindowProperty final
{
public:
    X11WindowProperty(Display *display, Window w, Atom property, long longOffset,
                      long longLength, Atom reqType)
    {
        if ( XGetWindowProperty(display, w, property, longOffset, longLength, false,
                                reqType, &type, &format, &len, &remain, &data) != Success )
        {
            data = nullptr;
        }
    }

    ~X11WindowProperty()
    {
        if (data != nullptr)
            XFree(data);
    }

    bool isValid() const
    {
        return data != nullptr;
    }

    X11WindowProperty(const X11WindowProperty &) = delete;
    X11WindowProperty &operator=(const X11WindowProperty &) = delete;

    Atom type{};
    int format{};
    unsigned long len{};
    unsigned long remain{};
    unsigned char *data;
};

Window getCurrentWindow()
{
    if (!QX11Info::isPlatformX11())
        return 0L;

    auto display = QX11Info::display();
    XSync(display, False);

    static Atom atomWindow = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW", true);

    X11WindowProperty property(display, DefaultRootWindow(display), atomWindow, 0l, 1l, XA_WINDOW);

    if ( property.isValid() && property.type == XA_WINDOW && property.format == 32 && property.len == 1)
        return *reinterpret_cast<Window *>(property.data);

    return 0L;
}



X11PlatformWindow::X11PlatformWindow(Window winId)
    : m_window(winId)
{
}


void X11PlatformWindow::raise()
{
    Q_ASSERT( isValid() );

    if (!QX11Info::isPlatformX11())
        return;


    auto display = QX11Info::display();

    XEvent e{};
    memset(&e, 0, sizeof(e));
    e.type = ClientMessage;
    e.xclient.display = display;
    e.xclient.window = m_window;
    e.xclient.message_type = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW", False);
    e.xclient.format = 32;
    e.xclient.data.l[0] = 2;
    e.xclient.data.l[1] = CurrentTime;
    e.xclient.data.l[2] = 0;
    e.xclient.data.l[3] = 0;
    e.xclient.data.l[4] = 0;

    XWindowAttributes wattr{};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, m_window, &wattr);

    if (wattr.map_state == IsViewable)
    {
        XSendEvent(display, wattr.screen->root, False,
                   SubstructureNotifyMask | SubstructureRedirectMask,
                   &e);
        XSync(display, False);
        XRaiseWindow(display, m_window);
        XSetInputFocus(display, m_window, RevertToPointerRoot, CurrentTime);
        XSync(display, False);
    }
}

void X11PlatformWindow::pasteClipboard()
{
    sendKeyPress(XK_Shift_L, XK_Insert);
//    sendKeyPress(XK_Shift_L, XK_Insert);
}

void X11PlatformWindow::copy()
{

}

bool X11PlatformWindow::isValid() const
{
    return m_window != 0L;
}

bool X11PlatformWindow::waitForFocus(int ms)
{
    Q_ASSERT( isValid() );

    if (ms >= 0)
    {
        SleepTimer t(ms);
        while (t.sleep())
        {
            const auto currentWindow = getCurrentWindow();
            if (currentWindow == m_window)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return m_window == getCurrentWindow();
}

void X11PlatformWindow::sendKeyPress(int modifier, int key)
{
    Q_ASSERT( isValid() );

    if ( !waitForFocus(50) )
    {
        raise();
        if ( !waitForFocus(150) )
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    waitMs(5000);

    if (!QX11Info::isPlatformX11())
        return;

    auto display = QX11Info::display();

    const int modifierMask = (modifier == XK_Control_L) ? ControlMask : ShiftMask;
    simulateKeyPress(display, m_window, modifierMask, key);

}
```

here is a test code from mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_button_clicked()
{
    clipboard = QApplication::clipboard();
    
    clipboard->setText("TEST");
    
    this->hide();

    X11PlatformWindow window(lastWindow); // the code I use to get the lastwindow is a little lengthy so I am omitting it

    window.raise();

    qDebug() << lastWindow;

    window.pasteClipboard();
}
```

This code is pasting the text to the Qt Creator editor and the browser's search bar.

My guess is that the window is being given input focus. `X11PlatformWindow::raise() is supposed to do that but I am not sure it's working.

I can't find how to know if `XSetInputFocus()` succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find how to know if XSetInputFocus() succeeded.

First step is to set X error handler, into which you pass your custom function pointer that will interpret generated errors.

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/protocol-errors/XSetErrorHandler.html

Errors which you want to handle for `XSetInputFocus` are:

> XSetInputFocus() can generate BadMatch, BadValue, and BadWindow
> errors.

https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XSetInputFocus.html

**EDIT:**

> Notes for X11 Users
>
> The X11 Window System has the concept of a separate selection and
> clipboard. When text is selected, it is immediately available as the
> global mouse selection. The global mouse selection may later be copied
> to the clipboard. By convention, the middle mouse button is used to
> paste the global mouse selection.
>
> X11 also has the concept of ownership; if you change the selection
> within a window, X11 will only notify the owner and the previous owner
> of the change, i.e. it will not notify all applications that the
> selection or clipboard data changed.
>
> Lastly, the X11 clipboard is event driven, i.e. the clipboard will not
> function properly if the event loop is not running. Similarly, it is
> recommended that the contents of the clipboard are stored or retrieved
> in direct response to user-input events, e.g. mouse button or key
> presses and releases. You should not store or retrieve the clipboard
> contents in response to timer or non-user-input events.
>
> Since there is no standard way to copy and paste files between
> applications on X11, various MIME types and conventions are currently
> in use. For instance, Nautilus expects files to be supplied with a
> x-special/gnome-copied-files MIME type with data beginning with the
> cut/copy action, a newline character, and the URL of the file.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html

This is exactly what you seem to do in your code:

**You should not store or retrieve the clipboard contents in response to timer or non-user-input events.**

Comment: I set the error handler, how do I see the the generated error code. Where in the code should I call XSetErrorHandler

Comment: The handler should be set in your `main` function before Window is created, inside of your custom handler you handle the error using `switch` or similar and handling individual error any way you want (ex. message box with error). the error lives in `XErrorEvent` pointer (function parameter).

Comment: I just did that but the handler never gets called. I am guessing there is no error being thrown by XSetInputFocus().

Comment: Looks like problem is in you code in `mainWindow.cpp`, I added notes and link in my post to help you identify problem.

Comment: I didn't really understand how that is affecting my code. I want to send a keypress event to a window, namely a ctrl+v that should paste the text. When I press the button in the application it pastes the text into the Qt creator editor  which indicates that the text is in the clipboard but does not paste in a text editor but that if directly press ctrl+v the text that was supposed to be pasted is pasted.

Comment: "You should not store or retrieve the clipboard contents in response to timer or non-user-input events." - Could you briefly explain what that means. Show where I am using it in my code and how I could fix it? I can't wrap my head around it.